# How to create a VMware template

Tags: vmware-esxi

Is it possible to create a VM Template on ESXi? I installed a Linux server on ESXi and I want to use this as a template.

Answer (score 7):

Yes and it is simple and you can do it even without vCenter. Open `vSphere Client`, select your VM (it has to be powered off), go to `File->Export->Export OVF Template...` and save it to your local drive. When you ready to create VM from it just do it through `File->Deploy OVF Template`.

Answer (score 5):

On ESXi?  Yes.

On a standalone, free-license ESXi device?  No. You need vSphere Server (nee Virtual Center) to create templates.

Comment: It isn´t a free Version, we have installed a "vSphere 4 Essentials" with a valid license. Why it dosn´t work?

Comment: What exactly have you been trying up to now?

Comment: @Marcus Are you connecting directly to the device, or through a vCenter server?  The option should be available when connected to vCenter.

Answer (score 5):

On the free ESXi you can enable Tech Support Mode and then once that is enabled you can connect to the host via SSH and use:

```
vmkfstools -i source.vmdk dest.vmdk -d thin
```

Then you can create a new VM using the file just created as an "Existing Disk".

It's not as convenient as as a Template, but it's better than nothing...

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

In Virutal Center right click on the Virtual Machine and select Template -> Convert to Template.

Comment: That´s the Point, there isn´t "Teamplate" Option. I use vSphere 4.1 Client to access the VMs.

Comment: This assumes that you have a vCenter server.  This isn't available without a vCenter server.

Comment: The question was asked with absolutely no additional information or context. Better questions typically result in better answers :-)